# How can I set terraform variables in acceptance testing?

Tags: terraform

I've got the following test setup:

```
func TestAccExampleThing_basic(t *testing.T) {
  /* ... potentially existing acceptance testing logic ... */

  resource.ParallelTest(t, resource.TestCase{
    /* ... existing TestCase functions ... */
    Steps: []resource.TestStep{
      /* ... existing TestStep ... */
      // step #2
      {
        ResourceName:      "example_thing.test",
        ImportState:       true,
        ImportStateVerify: true,
      },
    },
  })
}
```

where `step #2` essentially runs a terraform import. How can I pass the values for terraform variables to it? E.g.,

```
$ export TF_VAR_foo_id=abc123
$ terraform plan
```

and I want my test to run something like:

```
$ export TF_VAR_foo_id=abc123
$ terraform import foo_provider.foo_resource foo-bar // runs as a part of step #2
```

Comment: Is `var.foo_id` being used to define the resource? Or something else (such as provider configuration)? You wouldn't normally have variables like this in an acceptance test. If you wanted to avoid DRY type stuff you would put the hardcoded thing in a local instead. It might help if you can share more context, ideally as a [mcve].

Comment: `var.foo_id` is being used to define a resource, yes.

Comment: The questions is more like how to pass it.

Comment: Then the answer is that you shouldn't need to do that. Why do you think you need that? Can you share the configuration you are using in the acceptance test? Ideally you should aim for your question to include a [mcve] that shows exactly what you're doing because it might be that there's a much better solution to your problem.